# How to solve libatomic issue in windows?

Tags: c, windows, cmake, clang, llvm

I am developing executables from source code of llvm. So I downloaded the llvm source code from github.

I am trying everything from command line on `Windows OS`

I am following the link for libtooling in clang

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html

I tried with 2 options

> > Option First: I ran the below command
> >     `cmake -G Ninja "C:\Users\amith.ks\Desktop\Clang-llvm\llvm-project\llvm" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

Everything Worked..

> > Second option:
> >     I wan to set `cmake_c_compiler` and `cmake_cxx_compiler` from command line.
> >     I dont want to use cmake-gui so I run the below command
> >     `cmake -G Ninja "C:\Users\amith.ks\Desktop\Clang-llvm\llvm-project\llvm" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++`

From out of no where error was thrown

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckAtomic.cmake:53 (message):
  Host compiler appears to require libatomic, but cannot find it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/config-ix.cmake:343 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:617 (include)
```

When I saw the cmake error log It was saying this

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'atomic.lib'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1104 (use -v to see invocation)

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I searched my whole pc `atomic.lib` no where to be found.

How to solve this issue on windows?
Please help me with answers.

Answer (score 4):

I know why it fails. It's a bug in the LLVM's cmake files. In order to check if `atomic.lib` *is required* `CheckAtomic.cmake` tries compiling and linking a piece of code *with* `atomic.lib`. When it fails (because `atomic.lib` *is not required* and thus *is not present*) it falsely concludes that `atomic.lib` is needed. LLVM's cmake files is a hot mess with rarely fixed bugs. There are bugs staying there for years. I guess this is because nobody understands anymore how LLVM build system works.

Long story short, I couldn't find why `CheckAtomic.cmake` inserts `atomic.lib` while checking that it is not required. As a workaround I just unconditionally set `HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB` and `HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB` to `True` in `CheckAtomic.cmake`:

```
set(HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB True)
set(HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB True)
```

Comment: These two Cmake settings helped me to solve llvm build on macOS11.3. My issue - https://github.com/vgorloff/swift-everywhere-toolchain/issues/111

Comment: Thanks for quoting this post in the commit! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use clang-cl (or MSVC cl), they dont require lib atomic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to use Clang 11 (with MSVC ABI) to compile Clang 11. However, MSVC's headers won't compile in C++11 mode, which `CheckAtomic.cmake` uses:

`set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`

results in:

```
C:\Users\nyanpasu\code\llvm-project>clang  -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -std=c++11 uwu.cpp
In file included from uwu.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\atomic:19:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xatomic.h:13:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\type_traits:11:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xstddef:283:22: error: 'auto' return
      without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
_NODISCARD constexpr auto _Unfancy(_Ptrty _Ptr) noexcept { // converts from a fancy pointer to a plain pointer
                     ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't know if this is a MSVC bug where it ships an  header incompatible with C++11, or a Clang bug where it's using MSVC headers instead of its own.

In any case, changing c++11 to c++14 fixes this error.

Answer (score 0):

As lulle mentioned, you need to use the right tools to compile. If you have installed Visual Studio, use the Developer Command prompt for Visual Studio instead of a regular cmd and you'll have the environment variables you need. It is located in your Visual Studio installation directory, under the Tools subdirectory.

For example:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in macOS. Adding the CPP Libraries to the path solved it for me. You can try executing the following commands.

```
export SDKROOT="$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)"

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
```